# What's the difference between goog.require and goog.addDependency?

Tags: javascript, google-closure

when I put goog.require in to a HTML file..

base.js file definitely write script tag like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC-FILE}}closure-library/closure/goog/dom/dom.js"></script>
```

However, when I put a dependency file generated by depswriter.py..
it does not put any file required by other files.

so.. my question is..

1. what's the difference between goog.require and goog.addDependency?
2. can goog.addDependency replace goog.require? I mean, without any goog.require sentences, goog.addDependency can serve as goog.require?

please help me.. I spent more than 4 hours figuring out why the hell goog.addDependency does not incorporate dependency files into a HTML file and failed!!!..

Answer (score 3):

goog.require:

> Implements a system for the dynamic resolution of dependencies that works in parallel with the BUILD system.

goog.addDependency

> Adds a dependency from a file to the files it requires.

You don't have to use `goog.addDependency`. It's only used by the dependency generator scripts. You need to put deps.js in the same directory than base.js. Then put a script tag for loading base.js in your head section, followed by a script tag with your requires. Like that:

```
<script src="../base.js"></script>
<script>
    goog.require('goog.events.EventType');
    goog.require('goog.ui.AdvancedTooltip');
</script>
```

Have a look at the Closure demo: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/index.html

Comment: goog.addDependency is also used to do forward type declarations.  This is useful when your code references types declared in optionally included code.

Comment: Thanks!! since i'm a korean, it took a bit much time to understand. ^^ sorry for being late to click 'accept answer button'. how do you know all of this? wow.. awesome!